# WebSockets in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, websocket

I've started research with Websockets in Xamarin and i found something very weird. I used that simple code to connect my server and it did not get data from server but from itself...

System.Net.Websockets

```
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data from client");
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer),
```

// on the server side i change data to = "data from server"

```
            var buffer2 = new ArraySegment<Byte>(new Byte[4096]);
            var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer2, CancellationToken.None);
            var request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer2.Array, buffer2.Offset, buffer2.Count);
```

// in request i get = "data from client" why ?? seriously i dont have idea it will be very helpful if someone let me know what could be wrong

Thank u so much. :)

---

Solved. i've used code from **NVentimiglia/Websockets.PCL** implementation

Comment: Capture network packets to see what happened under the hood and report it back to the library developer.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the services or event frameworks out there specifically built for this instead of using raw sockets?  Handling differing network conditions, reconnections, state between servers, scale etc. is in most cases not something I have found you want to be engineering.  I know SignalR is quite popular in the .NET community.  **Disclaimer: I am the CEO of [Ably, a realtime data delivery platform](https://www.ably.io)**